# opencv 2.3.1 use bow , svm train images and load/save functions

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I'm a newbee in opencv and trying to classify two image categories with opencv2.3.1.
Here is my code.

```
void trainSVM(map<string,Mat>& classes_training_data, string& file_postfix, int response_cols, int response_type) {

//train 1-vs-all SVMs
vector<string> classes_names;
for (map<string,Mat>::iterator it = classes_training_data.begin(); it != classes_training_data.end(); ++it) {
    classes_names.push_back((*it).first);
}

string use_postfix = file_postfix;
for (int i=0;i<classes_names.size();i++) {
    string class_ = classes_names[i];

    Mat samples(0,response_cols,response_type);
    Mat labels(0,1,CV_32FC1);

    //copy class samples and label
    cout << "adding " << classes_training_data[class_].rows << " positive" << endl;
    samples.push_back(classes_training_data[class_]);
    Mat class_label = Mat::ones(classes_training_data[class_].rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
    labels.push_back(class_label);

    //copy rest samples and label
    for (map<string,Mat>::iterator it1 = classes_training_data.begin(); it1 != classes_training_data.end(); ++it1) {
        string not_class_ = (*it1).first;
        if(not_class_.compare(class_)==0) continue;
        samples.push_back(classes_training_data[not_class_]);
        class_label = Mat::zeros(classes_training_data[not_class_].rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
        labels.push_back(class_label);
    }

    cout << "Train.." << endl;
    Mat samples_32f; samples.convertTo(samples_32f, CV_32F);
    if(samples.rows == 0) continue; //phantom class?!
    CvSVM classifier; 
    classifier.train(samples_32f,labels);

    {
        stringstream ss; 
        ss << "SVM_classifier_"; 
        if(file_postfix.size() > 0) ss << file_postfix << "_";
        ss << class_ << ".yml";
        cout << "Save.." << endl;
        classifier.save(ss.str().c_str());
    }
}
}
```

I had saved the train file successfully.And when I'm trying to load the trained file using the below snippets:

```
classes_classifiers[catefory[i]].load(fclass.c_str());
```

it runs normally.
`svm.get_support_vector_count()`

it's true,too.
But when adds 
`svm.predict(descriptors,false);`

it would reports error

```
"OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The sample is not a valid vector) in cvPreparePredictData, file ~/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 1099
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  ~/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:1099: error: (-5) The sample is not a valid vector in function cvPreparePredictData"
```

Has any could help me to solve this problem?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe your predict variable `descriptors` is not a vector, commonly the `descriptors` has the same size with your one train sample data.
Here is my example code for opencv's SVM:

```
int sample_num = 100;
int feature_size = 256;
Mat_<float> train_data(sample_num,feature_size);
//put your train sample datas
...
Mat_<int> label_data(sample_num,1);
//put your train sample label
TermCriteria criteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON );
SVMParams param( SVM::C_SVC, SVM::RBF, 10.0, 8.0, 1.0, 10.0, 0.5, 0.1, NULL, criteria );
SVM svm;
//svm training
svm.train(train_data, label_data, Mat(), Mat(), param);
svm.save("svmtest.xml");
SVM _svm;
_svm.load("svmtest.xml");
Mat_<float> test_data(1,feature_size);
//put your test data
...
int predict_label = _svm.predict(test_data);
```

Comment: I had correct my code from your example. Thank you for your help!I couldn't login the stack overflow for a long time because of the GFW...

Comment: 哈哈 原来都是中国人啊。。。。。顺手点个赞呗~

Comment: 哈哈，今天最大的乐趣...声望不够点不了呀

Comment: 嗯嗯 没关系 加油 一起刷声望 我也是刚开始`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the load of your vocabulary.Before loading your trained data saved in your .yml file , you must save your vocabulary : when you are using BOW descriptors (BOWImgDescriptorExtractor & BOWKMeansTrainer) , so that you can load it in another project and compute with it the new descriptor for your test image and use your saved yml file for training. Wish this can help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I had saved vocabulary file successfully.